# What kind of k2pdfopt optimizations should I be using for these sample pages of a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I have a bunch of PDF files that follow this kind of layout:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I use k2pdfopt with options `-dev kp3 -fc -j -1 -jf -1 0.75 -n- -wrap -hy -ws -0.2`, I get this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the text gets mangled when I go for 'fit to single column'. Am doing this so I can easily read the matter on Kindle. Looking at the original PDF screenshots, what options should I be using for optimal kindle reading pdf to be generated?

I have access to a jailbroken Kindle Paperwhite (PW3) and Mac OS X. No Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this source has notes in the margins, use the -nl and -nr [options](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/options.shtml).  For [this example](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/stackexchange/20161007/), like so:

```
k2pdfopt -nl2e- -nr3o- source.pdf -o converted.pdf
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i just emailed you but please ignore it :)

Comment: Never got your e-mail.  Can you send again, please?  I'd like to ask you something else about your post.

Comment: PS.  If you have Office 365--it does a good job of [converting PDFs to MS Word format](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=3369956#post3369956) so that you could then more easily convert to mobi or epub.

Comment: done, sent email. thanks for the tip about office 365.